# QuickFIX/n: Detect errors

Tags: quickfixn

I've implemented an acceptor service using QuickFIX/n, and it seems like whenever any type of error, like a malformed incoming message or bad sequence numbers, occurs, QuickFIX/n hides the message and deals with the error internally.

Is there a way of programmatically detecting these errors without having to look in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the following response through the QuickFIX/n mailing list:

> No. Those are transport-layer errors, and they are not exposed to the
>   app layer because it is not appropriate for the app layer to attempt
>   recovery.
>
> I think transport errors are best handled by an external observer
>   process that can notify the maintainer.